# Is there a way to display static properties in a PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, static, propertygrid

I have a `PropertyGrid` that displays all of the instance properties for an object. Is there a way to also display the static properties of the class to which the object belongs, either in the same or a separate `PropertyGrid`? Alternatively, is there another Forms control that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Research using the [CustomTypeDescriptor Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.customtypedescriptor?view=netframework-4.8) to provide a customized view of an object.  There are a lot of examples of the basic procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type descriptors are responsible to provide list of properties to show in `PropertyGrid`.

To customize list of properties you need to provide custom type description for your class/object using either of the following options:

- Your class can implement [`ICustomTypeDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor?view=netcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- Your class can derive from [`CustomTypeDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.customtypedescriptor?view=netcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- You can create a new type descriptor for your class by driving from above interface/class and using a [`TypeDescriptionProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typedescriptionprovider?view=netcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) register it for your class or the object instance
- You can create a wrapper object by deriving from [`CustomTypeDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.customtypedescriptor?view=netcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) just to use for `PropertyGrid`.

**Example**

In this example I've implemented the last option. I assume you are going to keep the main class unchanged and just for purpose of showing in `PropertyGrid`, I've created a custom wrapper object which provides a list of properties for property grid, including the static properties.

Let's say you have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string InstanceProperty { get; set; }
    public static string StaticProperty { get; set; } = "Test";
}
```

And you want to show it's properties in `PropertyGrid`.

Then usually the first thing which you need is a new property descriptor:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
public class StaticPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    PropertyInfo p;
    Type owenrType;
    public StaticPropertyDescriptor(PropertyInfo pi, Type owenrType)
        : base(pi.Name,
              pi.GetCustomAttributes().Cast<Attribute>().ToArray())
    {
        p = pi;
        this.owenrType = owenrType;
    }
    public override bool CanResetValue(object c) => false;
    public override object GetValue(object c) => p.GetValue(null);
    public override void ResetValue(object c) { }
    public override void SetValue(object c, object v) => p.SetValue(null, v);
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object c) => false;
    public override Type ComponentType { get { return owenrType; } }
    public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return !p.CanWrite; } }
    public override Type PropertyType { get { return p.PropertyType; } }
}
```

Then you can use either of the options which I mentioned above. For example, here I've created a wrapper type descriptor to not touch the original class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
public class CustomObjectWrapper : CustomTypeDescriptor
{
    public object WrappedObject { get; private set; }
    private IEnumerable<PropertyDescriptor> staticProperties;
    public CustomObjectWrapper(object o)
        : base(TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(o).GetTypeDescriptor(o))
    {
        WrappedObject = o;
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        var instanceProperties = base.GetProperties(attributes)
            .Cast<PropertyDescriptor>();
        staticProperties = WrappedObject.GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Select(p => new StaticPropertyDescriptor(p, WrappedObject.GetType()));
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(
            instanceProperties.Union(staticProperties).ToArray());
    }
}
```

And the usage is quite easy:

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = new CustomObjectWrapper (myClass);
```

[image]

Comment: **Note:** The easiest workaround for you would be using instance properties which are wrappers around static properties.