# Generic CheckBox Creator function adding anonymous event handlers with referenced property

Tags: c#, winforms, lambda, ref

I want to create a bunch of simple checkboxes for a Windows from and have them change bools. Because it is a lot of them, I thought I could skip writing a bunch of CheckedChanged handlers and have a generic "Creator" function like this

```
    static CheckBox CreateCheckBox(ref bool binding, string name)
    {
        var box = new CheckBox();
        box.Checked = binding;
        box.CheckedChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { binding = !binding; };
        box.Text = name;
        return box;
    }
```

And Then create my boxes like:

```
ParentForm.Controls.Add(CreateCheckBox(ref prop1, nameof(prop1));
ParentForm.Controls.Add(CreateCheckBox(ref prop2, nameof(prop2));
.....
```

I obviously got the "Can't use ref in a lambda expression or anonymous function". I read up on it and it makes sense.
But is there a way to have this sort of simple creator function that that generically adds the handlers?

I know there would be an issue here with never removing the handler but this is for a debug mode feature that is only used by developers to debug and improve very specific.algorithm.
Maybe I am just being lazy to write and add all the handlers but I also just felt cleaner.

Comment: Instead of bool as your property, you could make a class that wraps that bool to make it a reference type.  Then you do not need to add the ref keyword.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish with the `ref` bool variable. Do you have some variable that you want to keep permanently synchronized with the `Checked` property? Why not just use the `Checked` property?

Comment: You do not need to pass anything by reference, use one of the following options: *1. Pass a getter Func and a setter Action* OR *2. Setup databinding*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to pass anything by reference, use one of the following options:

1. Pass a getter Func and a setter Action
2. Setup databinding

**Example 1 - Pass a getter Func or a setter Action**

Pass the getter and setter as func/action:

```
public CheckBox CreateCheckBox(string name, Func<bool> get, Action<bool> set)
{
    var c = new CheckBox();
    c.Name = name;
    c.Text = name;
    c.Checked = get();
    c.CheckedChanged += (obj, args) => set(!get());
    return c;
}
```

And use it like this, for example:

```
CreateCheckBox("checkBox1", () => textBox1.Enabled, (x) => textBox1.Enabled = x);
CreateCheckBox("checkBox2", () => textBox2.Enabled, (x) => textBox2.Enabled = x);
```

**Example 2 - Setup databinding**

What you are trying to implement is what you can achieve by setting up data binding:

```
public CheckBox CreateCheckBox(string name, object dataSource, string dataMember)
{
    var c = this.Controls[name] as CheckBox;
    c.Name = name;
    c.Text = name;
    c.DataBindings.Add("Checked", dataSource,
        dataMember, false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    return c;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
CreateCheckBox("checkBox1", textBox1, "Enabled");
CreateCheckBox("checkBox2", textBox2, "Enabled");
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I googled passed the DataBindings option. That was exactly my keyword.

Comment: I ended up going with option 1 actually, since my properties to bind to are all static so I can't just pass the dataSource object as far as I Understand. Is there a way to do Option 2 with statics? Just out of interest... My problem is well solved with option 1.

Comment: @TomM There might be some workarounds, for example by providing custom typedescriptor. I've shared an answer here for a question seeking for a solution to [show static properties in PropertyGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56370834/3110834), I'm not sure if it helps but it might be inspiring if you want to kill some time on this matter 

Comment: Anyhow, it looks like an interesting question (but not very common or useful for all). If I see the question, I'll share my idea if I have any.